# Fixing json data accidentally double encoded

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Accidentally wrote a ton of data into a native json column as a string due to converting it using `json_encode()` before saving with an ORM that already automatically converts objects/arrays into json.

Example:

```
"{\"created\":true,\"amount\":\"9.95\",\"number\":\"1381329132\",\"date\":{\"date\":\"2019-11-11 00:00:00.000000\",\"timezone_type\":3,\"timezone\":\"UTC\"}}"
```

How would I construct a repair query to update the column to be an actual json object based on the string data already in there?

MySQL 5.7

Note: This is exactly as the data would appear if pulled from the table in a select statement and is not meant to represent a value that would be added to an SQL statement. If it was meant to be used in an SQL statement, then it would not be considered double encoded.

Comment: can't you simply reverse it, going the steos backward.

Comment: that said , i can't see the double encoding in this valid json

Comment: @nbk if what's shown is the string stored in the database, it is clearly double-encoded; why do you think it isn't?

Comment: double encde means tehre are json in json but the onöly array is date, and all other json like created are normal, so wjhere is the double encoding, besides try to decode the  json and see that the result is an array

Comment: @nbk the double encoding is that an object like `{"foo":"bar"}` was encoded (resulting in a _string_ `{"foo":"bar"}`) and then encoded again resulting in a string `"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"` which was stored instead of the intended string `{"foo":"bar"}`

Comment: @ysth is correct in analysis. The PHP associative array was first encoded as a JSON string which was then encoded a second time before insertion into the DB, and by the rules of PHP's `json_encode()` function that second pass caused all the quotes between the left and right most quote to be escaped with a backslash because it saw it as a simple text representation not a JSON encoded object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSON_UNQUOTE for this:

```
update yourtable set yourcolumn=json_unquote(yourcolumn) where yourcolumn like '"%';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=54e11ad53fb30d967c325445d0e08874

Comment: this makes no sense inserting the string as it is creates already  valid json see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4c7c6eb297749afe256c592e405ed347

Comment: @nbk the insert creates the situation the questioner has initially - doubly encoded json in a column; the update fixes it.  that is the point of this question, not doing the insert correctly in the first place.

Comment: I think the confusion is coming in because the code block I posted appears as if something you'd drop straight into an SQL statement. If that was the case, then no, it is not double encoded. However, what you are seeing is the actual output pulled from the database which still shows the backslashes, which is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: This resolved the problem and restored all records to native JSON objects.

Comment: This really helps for legacy data and requires progressive migration, thanks for the answer!